# I want to send CSV file from React.js app to Node.js server. And then work with that CSV on the server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I don't know how to connect the React app and Node.js server. In my React app I have an input with type="file" where I upload my CSV file and then I press the button to send this file to the Node.js server.

Update:
My server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const CsvUpload = require("express-fileupload");

app.use(CsvUpload());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use('/EXPRESSENDPOINT',
    (req, res, next) => { console.log(req.body)});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Application listening on port 8080!');
});
```

My App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from 'axios'

function App() {
  const [csvFile, SetCsvFile] = useState();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div>
          Select file
          <input type="file" name="file" onChange={e => {
            SetCsvFile(e.target.files)
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', "FILENAME");
            formData.append('file', csvFile);

            const url = 'http://localhost:8080/EXPRESSENDPOINT';
            axios({
              method: 'POST',
              url: url,
              headers: {
                ContentType: 'multipart/form-data'
              },
              body: formData
            })
              .then(res => console.log(res))
              .catch(err => console.log(err));

          }} />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: do multi-part file upload

Answer (score 0):

your react code would be,

```
    const [csvFile, SetCsvFile] = useState();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', "FILENAME");
    formData.append('file', csvFile); 
    <input type="file" name="file" onChange={SetCsvFile(e.target.files[0])} />

    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/EXPRESSENDPOINT';
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            ContentType: 'multipart/form-data'
        },
        body: formData
    })
    .then(res => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

and nodejs backend is,

```
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const CsvUpload = require("express-fileupload");

    app.use(CsvUpload());
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.use('/EXPRESSENDPOINT',
            (req, res, next) => { console.log(req.body) });
```

extract out logic into function,

```
    handleler = (e) => {
      SetCsvFile(e.target.files[0])
    }
    <input type="file" name="file" onChange={handleler} />
```

or simply do this,

```
onChange={e => {
        SetCsvFile(e.target.files)
      }}
```

Comment: I have an error in SetCsvFile(e.target.files[0]).

src\App.js
  Line 43:63:  'e' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: Thank you for help, but I still have problems. My server's output is just {}, and it works only 6 times. After 6 outputs of "{}" it doesnt show anything...

Comment: I added my code in the question